# Python stdout and stdout.buffer capture

Tags: python, linux, buffer, stdout

Hey i want to prevent any stdouts from anywhere and capture it in a variable.

Now the problem:

I have two methods to print something in stdout

Method 1:

```
print("Normal Print")
```

Method 2:

```
fds: List[BinaryIO] = [sys.stdin.buffer, sys.stdout.buffer, sys.stderr.buffer]
fds[1].write(b"%d\n" % a)
fds[1].flush()
```

Now i tried something like this

```
from io import BufferedWriter, BytesIO, StringIO

mystdout = StringIO()
mystdout.buffer = BufferedWriter(raw=BytesIO())
sys.stdout = mystdout
```

But with this i  get no output at all.

How is the best way to archiev this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean that you get no output at all? It's in variable:

```
mystdout = StringIO()
mystdout.buffer = BufferedRandom(raw=BytesIO()) # You can read from BufferedRandom
sys.stdout = mystdout
sys.stdout.buffer.write(b"BUFFER")
print("PRINT")
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__ # Restore original stdout

print(mystdout.getvalue()) # PRINT
mystdout.buffer.seek(0)
print(mystdout.buffer.read()) b"BUFFER"
```

Comment: That i have to use BufferedRandom was my problem. Thanks alot this has done the trick!